# Fast Enumeration of a NSFetchedResult

Tags: ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller, fast-enumeration

So I have a `NSFetchedResultsController`. I have it working fine for normally displaying the data. I have a situation where I need to be able to enumarate through them. So I fetch the results as seen here:

```
if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {

        exit(-1);  // Fail
    }
```

I need to do some work with the data before I display it so I am assigning it to an array like this:

```
 arrVacationResults = [fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];
```

Works perfectly so far. I now have an array of fetchedObjects. I tried to use fast enumeration but how do I reference whats in each array. I assumed it was a dictionary of sort so I tried to do something like

```
for (NSDictionary *myVacation in arrVacationResults)
{

}
```

That fails because in `arrVacationResults` they are not `NSDictionaries`, so what are they?

Comment: FYI - I do hope you don't really have a call to `exit` in your code. Why not log the error and gracefully handle the issue?

Comment: Its on my "to-do list". Thanks for the reminder @rmaddy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an array of NSManagedObjects:

```
for (NSManagedObject *myVacation in arraVacationResults)
{
 //
 //  if you need to cast it as your entity
 //
    VacationResultEntity *entity = (VacationResultEntity *) myVacation;   
}
```